# Splitting an array into two subarrays with minimal sum

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math

My question is if given an array,we have to split that into two sub-arrays such that the absolute difference between the sum of the two arrays is minimum with a condition that the difference between number of elements of the arrays should be atmost one.

Let me give you an example.Suppose

Example 1: 100 210 100 75 340

Answer :

Array1{100,210,100} and Array2{75,340} --> Difference = |410-415|=5

Example 2: 10 10 10 10 40

Answer : Array1{10,10,10} and Array2{10,40} --> Difference = |30-50|=20

Here we can see that though we can divide the array into {10,10,10,10} and {40},we are not dividing because the constraint "the number of elements between the arrays should be atmost 1" will be violated if we do so.

Can somebody provide a solution for this ?

My approach:

->Calculate sum of the array

->Divide the sum by 2

->Let the size of the knapsack=sum/2

->Consider the weights of the array values as 1.(If you have come across the knapsack problem ,you may know about the weight concept)

->Then consider the array values as the values of the weights.

->Calculate the answer which will be array1 sum.

->Total sum-answer=array2 sum

This approach fails.

Calculating the two arrays sum is enough.We are not interested in which elements form the sum.

Thank you!

Source: This is an ICPC problem.

Comment: Which ICPC problem was it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an algorithm that works in O(n<sup>3</sup>) time, but I have no hard proof it is optimal. It seems to work for every test input I give it (including some with negative numbers), so I figured it was worth sharing.

You start by splitting the input into two equally sized arrays (call them `one[]` and `two[]`?). Start with `one[0]`, and see which element in `two[]` would give you the best result **if swapped**. Whichever one gives the best result, swap. If none give a better result, don't swap it. Then move on to the next element in `one[]` and do it again.

That part is O(<sup>2</sup>) by itself. The problem is, it might not get the best results the first time through. If you just keep doing it until you don't make any more swaps, you end up with an ugly bubble-type construction which makes it O(n<sup>3</sup>) total.

Here's some ugly Java code to demonstrate (also at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/5Epzig) if you want to play with it):

```
static int[] input = {1,2,3,4,5,-6,7,8,9,10,200,-1000,100,250,-720,1080,200,300,400,500,50,74};

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    int[] two = new int[input.length/2];
    int[] one = new int[input.length - two.length];

    int totalSum = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        totalSum += input[i];
        if(i<one.length)
            one[i] = input[i];
        else
            two[i-one.length] = input[i];
    }

    float goal = totalSum / 2f; 

    boolean swapped;
    do{
        swapped = false;
        for(int j=0;j<one.length;j++){
            int curSum = sum(one);
            float curBestDiff = Math.abs(goal - curSum);
            int curBestIndex = -1;

            for(int i=0;i<two.length;i++){
                int testSum = curSum - one[j] + two[i];
                float diff = Math.abs(goal - testSum);
                if(diff < curBestDiff){
                    curBestDiff = diff;
                    curBestIndex = i;
                }
            }

            if(curBestIndex >= 0){  
                swapped = true;
                System.out.println("swapping " + one[j] + " and " + two[curBestIndex]);
                int tmp = one[j];
                one[j] = two[curBestIndex];
                two[curBestIndex] = tmp;
            }
        }
    } while(swapped);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(one));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(two));
    System.out.println("diff = " + Math.abs(sum(one) - sum(two)));
}

static int sum(int[] list){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
        sum += list[i];
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information on the upper limit of the input?

For your algorithm, I think your are trying to pick floor(n/2) items and find it's maximum sum of value as array1 sum...(If this is not your original thought then please ignore the following lines)

If this is the case, then knapsack size should be n/2 instead of sum/2,

but even so, I think it's still not working. The ans is `min(|a - b|)` and maximizing `a` is a different issue. For eg, {2,2,10,10}, you will get a = 20, b = 4, while the ans is a = b = 12.

To answer the problem, I think I need more information of the upper limit of the input..
I cannot come up with a brilliant dp state but a 3-dimensional state

`dp(i,n,v) := in first i-th items, pick n items out and make a sum of value v`

each state is either 0 or 1 (false or true)

`dp(i,n,v) = dp(i-1, n, v) | dp(i-1, n-1, v-V[i])`

This dp state is so naive that it has a really high complexity which usually cannot pass a ACM / ICPC problem, so if possible please provide more information and see if I can come up another better solution...Hope I can help a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

DP soluction will give lg(n) time. Two array, iterate one from start to end, and calculate the sum, the other iterate from end to start, and do the same thing. Finally, iterate from start to end and get minimal difference.